# Setting elements to None in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not sure why this happens

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3),columns=list('ABC'))
>>> df
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
```

Assign `None` to elements in last row turns it into `NaN NaN NaN`:

```
>>> df.ix[5,:] = None
>>> df
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9  10  11
4  12  13  14
5 NaN NaN NaN
```

Change two element in last column to 'nan'

```
>>> df.ix[:1,2] = 'nan'
>>> df
    A   B    C
0   0   1  nan
1   3   4  nan
2   6   7    8
3   9  10   11
4  12  13   14
5 NaN NaN  NaN
```

Now last row becomes `NaN NaN  None`

```
>>> df.ix[5,:] = None
>>> df
    A   B     C
0   0   1   nan
1   3   4   nan
2   6   7     8
3   9  10    11
4  12  13    14
5 NaN NaN  None
```

Comment: You probably want `np.nan`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I could have used some other string in place of 'nan', the effect is the same

Comment: If you use  `df.ix[:1,2] = np.nan` then, `df.ix[5,:] = None` will work as expected for you because `C` column will be a `float` so not sure what you mean. It seems like MaxU edited it in his accepted answer too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your dtypes are being changed after each assignment:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3),columns=list('ABC'))

In [8]: df.dtypes
Out[8]:
A    int32
B    int32
C    int32
dtype: object

In [9]: df.loc[5,:] = None

In [10]: df.dtypes
Out[10]:
A    float64
B    float64
C    float64
dtype: object

In [11]: df.loc[:1,2] = 'nan'
```

after that last assignment the `C` column has been implicitly converted to `object` (string) dtype:

```
In [12]: df.dtypes
Out[12]:
A    float64
B    float64
C     object
dtype: object
```

[@ayhan has written very neat answer as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434733/setting-elements-to-none-in-pandas-dataframe/39434877#comment66192432_39434877):

> I think the main reason is for numerical columns, when you insert None
>   or np.nan, it is converted to np.nan to have a Series of type float.
>   For objects, it takes whatever is passed (if None, it uses None; if
>   np.nan, it uses np.nan -
>   [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#inserting-missing-data))
>
> (c) [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/ayhan)

Here is a corresponding demo:

```
In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5,3),columns=list('ABC'))

In [40]: df.loc[4, 'A'] = None

In [41]: df.loc[4, 'C'] = np.nan

In [42]: df
Out[42]:
     A   B     C
0  0.0   1   2.0
1  3.0   4   5.0
2  6.0   7   8.0
3  9.0  10  11.0
4  NaN  13   NaN

In [43]: df.dtypes
Out[43]:
A    float64
B      int32
C    float64
dtype: object

In [44]: df.loc[0, 'C'] = 'a string'

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
     A   B         C
0  0.0   1  a string
1  3.0   4         5
2  6.0   7         8
3  9.0  10        11
4  NaN  13       NaN

In [46]: df.dtypes
Out[46]:
A    float64
B      int32
C     object
dtype: object
```

now we can use both `None` and `np.nan` for the `object` dtype:

```
In [47]: df.loc[1, 'C'] = None

In [48]: df.loc[2, 'C'] = np.nan

In [49]: df
Out[49]:
     A   B         C
0  0.0   1  a string
1  3.0   4      None
2  6.0   7       NaN
3  9.0  10        11
4  NaN  13       NaN
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: I think the main reason is for numerical columns, when you insert None or np.nan, it is converted to np.nan to have a Series of type float. For objects, it takes whatever is passed (if None, it uses None; if np.nan, it uses np.nan - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#inserting-missing-data))

Comment: @ayhan, it's a very neat answer, thank you! I've added it to the answer